TED spread replacement and other worthwhile market indicators?
Would I be right in thinking that the St. Louis Fed Financial Stress Index, would be the nearest replacement for the old TED spread?
Any other indicators worth looking at?
I use the well known HYIOAS (ICE BofA US High Yield Index Option Adjusted Spread), but hoping to find others that are useful with regards to stocks and bonds.

This was asked before https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69944 BSBY is dead, but Ameribor is still published and probably its spread is closest to TED

Thanks for that. Does the Overnight Unsecured AMERIBOR Benchmark Interest Rate offer much in the way of signals for the markets, in general?

Also https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/50514/54838

Lots of people wonder these days what might be good early warning indicators, test their effectiveness empirically/historically, the only general agreement is that you should monitor many.
